# Reading files not vary by encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I write app which have to read lines from TXT files (files are stored in ZIP archive, so I use c# streams to unpack them and operate in memory) and proceed them.

Input files are encoded like ASCII or UTF8 (I don't know which is which). Data contains strings which contains polish or czech chars. File are small (1-5kB)

First question When I force read files like UTF8, polish letters are not correct display from ASCII file, and the other way. Any idea? How can I in easy way detect file encoding? Is this info keep in TXT file metadata?

Second question: When I display TXT file in NotePad++ I can see how file is encoded. How NotePad++ knows that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I suspect you don't really mean ASCII... what *exactly* do you mean? (There are no accented characters in ASCII, and every ASCII file can be treated as UTF-8 without changing its meaning.)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should not force *any encoding*:

```
  String text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyFile.txt");
```

The system (as well as NotePad+) will try to detect the actual encoding by using so called **BOM** (Byte Order Mark)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark